# Exposing a /dev/uio* file from GPIO input driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, tuio

I have made a custom kernel module to handle rising edge triggered interrupts on a GPIO. I want to make a "uio" file for the same in /dev directory. What must I do? Do I need to declare some structures and fill it out ? It would be good if someone could share relevant examples.

Below is the code snippet for the cutom GPIO driver that triggers interrupts.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>                 // Required for the GPIO functions
#include <linux/interrupt.h>            // Required for the IRQ code

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Khilav Soni");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A Switch test driver");

static unsigned int gpio_switch = 65;   ///< hard coding the button gpio for this example to P9_27 (GPIO65)
static unsigned int irq_number;          ///< Used to share the IRQ number within this file

/// Function prototype for the custom IRQ handler function -- see below for the implementation
static irq_handler_t ebbgpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs);

/** @brief The LKM initialization function
 *  The static keyword restricts the visibility of the function to within this C file. The __init
 *  macro means that for a built-in driver (not a LKM) the function is only used at initialization
 *  time and that it can be discarded and its memory freed up after that point. In this example this
 *  function sets up the GPIOs and the IRQ
 *  @return returns 0 if successful
 */
static int __init ebbgpio_init(void){
   int result = 0;
   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: Initializing the GPIO_TEST LKM\n");
   gpio_request(gpio_switch, "sysfs");       // Set up the gpioButton
   gpio_direction_input(gpio_switch);        // Set the button GPIO to be an input
   gpio_set_debounce(gpio_switch, 100);      // Debounce the button with a delay of 200ms
   //gpio_export(gpio_switch, false);          // Causes gpio115 to appear in /sys/class/gpio
                                // the bool argument prevents the direction from being changed
   // Perform a quick test to see that the button is working as expected on LKM load
   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The button state is currently: %d\n", gpio_get_value(gpio_switch));

   // GPIO numbers and IRQ numbers are not the same! This function performs the mapping for us
   irq_number = gpio_to_irq(gpio_switch);
   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The button is mapped to IRQ: %d\n", irq_number);

   // This next call requests an interrupt line
   result = request_irq(irq_number,             // The interrupt number requested
                        (irq_handler_t) ebbgpio_irq_handler, // The pointer to the handler function below
                        IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,   // Interrupt on rising edge (button press, not release)
                        "switch-event",    // Used in /proc/interrupts to identify the owner
                        NULL);                 // The *dev_id for shared interrupt lines, NULL is okay

   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The interrupt request result is: %d\n", result);
   return result;
}

/** @brief The LKM cleanup function
 *  Similar to the initialization function, it is static. The __exit macro notifies that if this
 *  code is used for a built-in driver (not a LKM) that this function is not required. Used to release the
 *  GPIOs and display cleanup messages.
 */
static void __exit ebbgpio_exit(void){
   free_irq(irq_number, NULL);               // Free the IRQ number, no *dev_id required in this case
   gpio_unexport(gpio_switch);               // Unexport the Button GPIO
   gpio_free(gpio_switch);                   // Free the Button GPIO
}

/** @brief The GPIO IRQ Handler function
 *  This function is a custom interrupt handler that is attached to the GPIO above. The same interrupt
 *  handler cannot be invoked concurrently as the interrupt line is masked out until the function is complete.
 *  This function is static as it should not be invoked directly from outside of this file.
 *  @param irq    the IRQ number that is associated with the GPIO -- useful for logging.
 *  @param dev_id the *dev_id that is provided -- can be used to identify which device caused the interrupt
 *  Not used in this example as NULL is passed.
 *  @param regs   h/w specific register values -- only really ever used for debugging.
 *  return returns IRQ_HANDLED if successful -- should return IRQ_NONE otherwise.
 */
static irq_handler_t ebbgpio_irq_handler(unsigned int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs){
   static unsigned int numberPresses = 0;  ///< For information, store the number of button presses
   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: Interrupt! (button state is %d)\n", gpio_get_value(gpio_switch));
   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: The button was pressed %d times\n", numberPresses);
   numberPresses++;                         // Global counter, will be outputted when the module is unloaded
   return (irq_handler_t) IRQ_HANDLED;      // Announce that the IRQ has been handled correctly
}

/// This next calls are  mandatory -- they identify the initialization function
/// and the cleanup function (as above).
module_init(ebbgpio_init);
module_exit(ebbgpio_exit);
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. Have you read https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/uio-howto.html ? Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: Yes, I went through the doc but it does not help me. I want to create a "/dev/uio*" entry and perform a 'read" operation on it. The 'read' blocks until there is not rising edge interrupt on my GPIO. When an interrupt occurs on the specified GPIO pin, the read unblocks and allows me to perform relevant operation. How do I do this ?

Comment: same situation here ... my kernel modules looks exactly like yours and the uio-howto does not help me out ... did you find a solution?